# Execute JavaScript when visiting a specific page that I don’t control

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firefox-addon

Is it possible to execute a JavaScript function when I visit a specific site? For example, I visit https://google.com and the browser executes my function when the site loads. I’m using Firefox.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: You don't need greasemonkey etc. This is a very simple addon that injects code when a github page is loaded - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-expand-all-commit-notes/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you would need a browser plugin to do it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons

Answer (score 0):

Check this chrome extension:

Run custom JavaScript on any website.
Use this tool to inject custom javascript in any website.

Your scripts are kept in the local storage and applied across domain URLs.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en